# Eclipse lists files twice in nested projects

Tags: eclipse

I have a Maven module `foo` which contains a module `bar` which contains a file `readme.txt`. So the directory structure is `foo/bar/readme.txt`. I loaded the modules into Eclipse as projects. When I press Ctrl+Shift+R and try to load `readme.txt`, Eclipse gives me two options: `foo/bar/readme.txt` and `bar/readme.txt`. How can I cause Eclipse to only propose one of the two?

One option is to use working sets. Is there another option?

Comment: Is there a way to use linked folders to limit Eclipse's proposed files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Filter Duplicated Resource" filter in the Open Resource dialog.

This is found in the dialog menu (click the three vertical dots at the top right of the dialog).